# How can I display a total for a calculated column in a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, list, sum

I have a column, B, that is calculated based on another column, A. At the top of the list, I'd like to display the sum of B. When I look in the Totals section in the Create/Modify a Column screen, I only see column A (actually, I only see all the non-calculated columns), so I can't choose to sum column B.

Is there a way to display a total for column B?

Answer (score 2):

I found something that feels like a hack, but it works:

1. Using a web browser, edit your
   desired list to use “Totals” on at
   least one column in your list.
2. Open
   your desired SharePoint site in
   SharePoint Designer.
3. In the Folder
   List view, find your desired list in
   the Lists folder.
4. Open
   AllItems.aspx (or whatever view you
   want to edit).
5. In the Web Parts
   inspector, Web Parts tab, click the
   "*Username* Gallery" and the Web Part
   List below that will display a list
   that includes a Content Editor Web
   Part (CEWP).
6. Drag the CEWP into the
   AllItems.aspx (or whatever) view you
   have open.
7. Save the aspx file.
8. Go
   to [this JQuery web page](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/01/06/jquery-for-everyone-total-calculated-columns/) and copy
   whichever script you're interested
   in to the clipboard.
9. Go to your
   SharePoint list using a web browser.
10. You'll see a line of text there now,
    where you put the CEWP: "To add
    content, open the tool pane and then
    click Rich Text Editor." Click on
    the "open the tool pane" link.
11. Click the Source Editor button on the right.
12. Paste the
    script in the clipboard into the
    Source Editor window.
13. Change the 
    "var col = 4; //which column to sum"
    line so that the column number is
    the one you want to sum.
14. Click the
    Save button and then the OK button in
    the bottom right.

Voila!

Unfortunately, this solution is very brittle. If you make any changes to the page in SharePoint Designer and save the aspx file again, the script code that you put in the CEWP is lost and you have to re-paste it back in again. To make it less brittle, you can just reference the code in a separate file. To do this, remove the code from the CEWP's Source Editor, save the code as a ".js" file in another SharePoint list (e.g., create a new one called "Resources"), copy the URL of that file, and paste the URL into the text box under "To link to a text file, type a URL".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a SharePoint data view you can display the count of a column using XSL

```
< xsl:value-of select="sum(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@ColumnName)" />
```

In your case the code will have Column B eg:

```
< xsl:value-of select="sum(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@column B)" />
```